# Is this equality true? Any sources?

Tags: reference-request

Is it true that $1 - \frac 12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots-\frac 1{200}=\frac 1{101}+\frac 1{102}+\cdots+\frac 1{200}$? Where can I find sources for this proof?

Comment: For a boring proof, try induction. Go from $2$ to $4$ to $6$ and so on.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : induction? It does not work.. i tried that...

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : how can you edit the question if it also changes the meaning of the question...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I have lots of reputation and so the privilege to edit posts at will. The OP can always contest my edits, and if I am found to have done something wrong, the moderators can sanction me. In this case, there was an obvious mistake in the formula. I used my judgement to decide that rather than answering "no", I would correct the typo.

Comment: Hi Praphulla Koushik, Yuval Filmus was correct, I made a typo and started at $\frac 1{100}$ instead of $\frac 1{101}$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : You can ofcourse edit the question as you have lots of reputation but the question was totally different than your edit.. that is what my point is... I was not so sure that is an obvious mistake or not...

Comment: @someone : I know that he is correct.. I was saying you are the one who is supposed to edit the mistakes...

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : The comment that i have made was supposed to be noted for OP... I did {@}your name by mistake..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I am a new user here, how can I edit my post? I thought only users with lots of reputation can do it, as Yuval Filmus wrote.

Comment: @someone : YOu can not edit other's post but you can definitely edit yours...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Add 
$$2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots+\frac{1}{200}\right)$$to both sides.

Comment: Oh.. fine :) :)

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{r=n+1}^{2n}\frac1r=\sum_{r=1}^{2n}\frac1r-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1r$$

$$=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1{2r-1}+\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1{2r}-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1r$$

Now
$$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1{2r}-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1r=\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac1{2r}-\frac1r\right)=-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1{2r}$$

Comment: This  answer is for previous question or this edited question???

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, I reached  at$$\sum_{r=n+1}^{2n}\frac1r=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1{2r-1}-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1{2r}$$

Comment: :) You are very careful  about what you say :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the boring proof by induction. We want to prove that
$$ 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{n+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n}. $$
Base case: $n = 1$. The left-hand side reads $1-1/2 = 1/2$, and the right-hand side is $1/2$.

Induction step: Suppose
$$ 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{n+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n}. $$
Then
$$
\begin{align*}
&1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+2} \\ =
&1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+2} \\ =
&\frac{1}{n+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+2} \\ =
&\frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+2} \\ =
&\frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+2}. \end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

To make this a bit easier to think about...
$$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{200} \frac{1}{r} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{199} + \frac{1}{200}$$

Subtract the even fractions between 1/2 and 1/200:
$$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{200} \frac{1}{r} - \sum\limits_{r=1}^{100} \frac{1}{2r}= 1 + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{199}$$

Take the even fractions off *again*
$$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{200} \frac{1}{r} - 2\sum\limits_{r=1}^{100} \frac{1}{2r}= 1 -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{199} - \frac{1}{200}$$

Now,
$$2\sum\limits_{r=1}^{100} \frac{1}{2r} = \sum\limits_{r=1}^{100} \frac{1}{r}$$

So the left-hand side becomes:

$$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{200} \frac{1}{r} - \sum\limits_{r=1}^{100} \frac{1}{r}$$
$$ = \sum\limits_{r=101}^{200} \frac{1}{r}
 = \frac{1}{101} + \frac{1}{102} + \cdots + \frac{1}{200} $$ 
*(quod erat demonstrandum)*